# VB Script Keeps giving me "Macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I've been trying to make a simple VBS that just opens Excel and runs a specific macro.  I swear months ago when I wrote this it had worked.  I've scoured the forums for similar errors and nothing suggested seems to have worked for me.

Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.DisplayAlerts=false
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lnguy\Desktop\New Chemical Receipt Form.xlsm", 0, True)

xlApp.Run "'C:\Users\lnguy\Desktop\New Chemical Receipt Form.xlsm'!Expired2"

xlBook.Close

xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: To the `Run` method you pass a path that is missing the `FTO Development\` part.

Comment: Where is this macro being stored? Where's the rest of your macro? What line does it error out on (or does it just do so in general)?

Comment: Sorry just realized I copied and pasted the wrong path.  I edited the code with the correct path and it still doesn't work.  The macro is stored on sheet1 of the excel worksheet.  The vbs script errors out on the .Run line.  I have added a reference to the sheet as Sheet1!Expired2 for the macro and it does not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have a different path the second time you mention it (`FTO Development\` is missing), so the macro cannot be found.

I would suggest to prevent this from happening by using a variable for the path:

```
Dim path
path = "C:\Users\lnguy\Desktop\FTO Development\New Chemical Receipt Form.xlsm"

' ....

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, True)

xlApp.Run "'" & path & "'!Expired2"
```

Comment: Sorry I copied and pasted the wrong paths there.. Even with using a variable as a path, it gives me the error on the .Run line.

Comment: What happens if you open the Excel file manually. Do you get a warning about security on running macros? Is the macro created as a `Public Sub`? Can you run it from Excel?

Comment: I can run the macro from excel.

Comment: Could you also come back to me on the other two questions?

Comment: Could you give some feed-back?

Comment: Trincot, the macros are run in a trusted location so no warnings there.  The macro is under private sub.

Answer (score 0):

Move the macro from Worksheet1 into its own module and ensure it's a `Public Sub` so it can be referenced.